# Validating URL Query string in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

A correctly formed query string looks like:

```
http://baseurl.thing/update?id=123&foo=50&bar20
```

I want to map this "safely" into an object, but I don't want to end up with undefined values. Is there a nice way of validating the query string?

Details: I want to turn this into an object with the `url` module. i.e.:

```
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
```

and then I can route based on `url_parts.pathname`. I want to access `url_parts.query.id`, `url_parts.query.foo` and `url_parts.query.bar`, but only if they all exist and only if no other parameters were supplied, so that I don't get silent undefined values appearing.

Comment: I don't get it. You have the `query` object already, so why not just do `if (query.id && query.foo && query.bar) { ... }`?

Comment: I wanted to check that no other parameters were supplied, ie that it conforms exactly. I guess I can just ignore other parameters if it's a pain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set up defaults, and then overwrite them with values from your url.

EXAMPLE

```
var defaults = {
    id : 0,
    foo : 'default value',
    bar : 'default.value'
};

var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
query.prototype = defaults; //does the inheritance of defaults thing
// now query has all values set, even if they didn't get passed in.
```

Hope that helps!